# Is there a DirectX cheat sheet?

Tags: directx

I tried searching for a DirectX cheat sheet but only came up with this one for DirectX 10:

http://www.inmensia.com/articulos/directx/directx_d3d10_cheat_sheet.html

What I am really interested in is DirectX 9 and 11.

Are there any cheat sheets available for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably the best "cheat sheet" is MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh309465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx